# Как проверить, является ли класс компонентом React?

Tags: reactjs

Я думал, можно проверить с помощью `istanceof` однако, это не работает.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {}

console.log(Test instanceof React.Component);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Подскажите, как можно проверять, является ли класс компонентом React

Comment: Потому что Test и не является экземпляром React.Component. Вообще, в терминах ООП Test — это нифига не объект, Test — это класс; см. [How to test if B is a “subclass” of A in Javascript/Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939192/how-to-test-if-b-is-a-subclass-of-a-in-javascript-node)

Comment: Спасибо исправил. Ну так сделайте ответом )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Test extends React.Component {}

console.log(!!Test.prototype.isReactComponent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```